# How do I add a group Managed Service Account to a newly created domain, add to security group, and assign the account to that group of computers?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi, gmsa

With a newly create domain, the SQL Servers require a group Managed Service Account (gMSA) to run their services.  What are steps from assigning a Kerberos capability to the gMSA through creating the Security Group in the domain, to assigning the computers to the security group and providing the machines in that group, the ability to pull the accounts using the PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword parameter, and possibly deal with the inital WMI error while trying to assign the gMSA to the database engine on SQL Server?

Comment: This would be best posted on [su] or [sf]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a group Managed Service Account using the Active Directory PowerShell module by running

> New-ADServiceAccount -name gmsaSQL -DNSHostName gmsaSQL.contoso.com

- Install the gMSA to the Managed Services Accounts in the Active Directory

> Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity gmsaSQL

- Test if the gMSA is working properly

> Test-ADServiceAccount -Identity gmsaSQL

- Create an Active Directory Organizational Unit in the Active Directory

> New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Security Groups" -Path
> "DC=Contoso,DC=com"

- Create an Active Directory Security Group in the new OrganizationalUnit

> New-ADGroup -Name "SQL Servers" -GroupScope Global -GroupCategory
> Security -Path "OU=Security Groups,DC=Contoso,DC=com"

- Add computer objects to Security Group

> Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=SQL Servers,OU=Security
> Groups,DC=Contoso,DC=com" -Members "MyComputer$"

- Assign the gMSA to SQL Server security group (later add other computers if required)

> Set-ADServiceAccount -Identity gmsaSQL
> -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword "SQL Servers"

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager on each server where SQL Server services are installed
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, select SQL Server Services in
  the left pane.
- In the right pane, right-click on SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and select
  Properties.
- In the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) Properties dialog box, click on the
  Log On tab.
- Select the This account option and enter the name of the    gmsaSQL$
  service account in the format contoso\gmsaSQL$.
- Click on OK to save the changes.
- If a WMI error occurs upon assignment, check the MOF file in the program files (x86) path
- To resolve any WMI Provider Error that may occur, you can try repairing or recreating MOF file using mofcomp command. After running this command, restart WMI service for changes to take effect.

Comment: Giving credit to AI though everything above was painstakingly tested including putting up a new domain controller on Windows 2022 for the testing.   There is also a good post here https://blog.matrixpost.net/set-up-group-managed-service-accounts-gmsa/